# unsetting a $_SESSION variable after echoing it alters the view

Tags: php, unset, ob-start

I'm using the $_SESSION to store messages to display to the user.

```
$_SESSION['message']['error']=" an error appear",
$_SESSION['message']['warning']="not good !"
```

my HTML page is generated by including some HTML views and and generating variables.

This is done between `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean()`

Then i'm echoing the result to the user.

After that i unset `$_SESSION['message']` to left a clean situation for the next pages.

it seems that the unsetting is parallelised with the `ob_start()`

When i comment the unset, i've got the right messages displayed.
But when I uncomment it the messages are displayed empty.

I've tried to unset the `$_SESSION['message']` at different position in my code. I have tried setting it to an empty array.

It seems that the PHP core is doing some optimisation and interpreting my code in an inappropriate order.

***It Looks kinda like this:***

```
ob_start();

$ctrl = new $classeControleur();
$ctrl->$action();

$contenu = ob_get_clean();

include CHEMIN_VUE.'header.view.php';

require('aside.php');
echo '<div id="portail_application_centre">';
echo $contenu;
echo '<div>';

// HTML END

unset($_SESSION['message']);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: assign $_SESSION['message'] to a variable, then unset $_SESSION['message']

Comment: That's what i'm doing. Under the " $ctrl->$action()  ". A method check if  $_SESSION['message'] exist and store the message in $message. i then echo $message in the VIEW. It seems that the unset is done between ob_start and ob_get_clean ! THanks

Comment: My question is " could it be possible that the PHP core decide to perform the unset during the buffering although i'm to do it after !" ... (PHP 7.2.24 BY THE WAY )

Comment: What does the `$ctrl->$action()` actually do? Looking how you call it, it looks like it can call different methods depending on the value of `$action`. Are you echoing the value of the session in the method that's called? Because I can't see you outputting the session value anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that sessions in PHP are blocking and only one process can access given session file at a time - any other process trying to access the same session will sit and wait for its turn.
Once you open session and it will block forever until you either close it or program finish by itself and exit.

$_SESSION superglobal holds key/value pairs that belong to last open session, but this variable is not session itself. It allows you to modify open session and it remembers data from previously opened session, nothing more.

You have to start session manually (unless configured otherwise in php.ini - don't do it) before you can write to it. What you need to do is to open session, make changes, then close it right away. You can reopen it later if needed.

Always close session as soon as you are done writing to it, so other process can access it and save their changes. If you leave it open no one will be able to save any changes.

Here I made a little example how to access session data couple times during one run of the script.

```
<?php

// we check if session is already open or not
// in another included file for example
if (!session_id()) {
  // now we create new session if it doesn't exists
  // or reopen and continue previous one
  session_start();
}

// session is now open so we can we can save a value inside
$_SESSION['last_seen'] = time();

// we can also remove existing values
unset($_SESSION['user_favourite_color']);

// we can read saved values if they exists
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo 'Hello '. $_SESSION['username'] .'!'. PHP_EOL;
  echo 'Yes I REMEMBER YOU!' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'I DONT KNOW YOU! I see you for the first time.'. PHP_EOL;
  $_SESSION['username'] = 'Mr USERNAME';
  echo 'Now I noted your name, I will remember you.'. PHP_EOL;
}

// now we close session to not block it any longer
// maybe some other process is waiting to use it
session_write_close();

// here you do some other stuff
// lets sleep for example
sleep(2);

// you can reopen the same session
// but remember something might have changed
// since you had it open last time (before sleep)
// like maybe in different browser tab, just keep that in mind
session_start();
$_SESSION['visit'] += 1;
unset($_SESSION['something']);

// and we should close it again to make sure our changes are saved
session_write_close();
```

Let me know if that's any help.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some advice.  My code is running under a web portal. It's the web portal that start the sessions for the client code. the application use extensively the session to store data. But rarely unset a variable under the session.  The session seems to work fine and i don't have the ability to modify it directly.It seems the : ... 
 unset($_SESSION['message']);<code>  ....is executed between the ob_start and the ob_get_clean. Or that there's a "gohst reference" that modify the view after it has been transfered to the browser ( I know it's strange)

Comment: Well, sessions are really not good to store anything more than simple flags (like $_SESSION['is_logged'] = 1) . They are based on files, they are always blocking and data they store is practically lost not only when you destroy it, but also when user lose cookie with session ID, so you can end up with tons of zombie temp files waiting for expiration date. For temporary data I would use shared memory instead with extensions like "shmop" - it's soooo fast and fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution with a senior DEV at the office.

Some more explanations:

I use MVC with a frontend controller.The code i presented is a portion of the frontend controller.

We get `$action` from `$_GET['action']` and `$ctrl` from  `$_GET['ctrl']`. Then we execute the method `action()` from the controller `ctrl()`. The method does some logic and update `$_SESSION['message']` if i need to inform the user.  Then,`$_SESSION['message']` is stored in `$message` and subsequently there's a `echo $message;` in the appropriate VIEW. finally the buffer is flushed to $contenu which is send  to the user by the `echo $contenu;` line. Then i thought it was secure to unset the `$_SESSION['message']` because it has already been send. But surpisingly, it is empty. It is not if i comment the unset line but then i sent unsolicited message to the user throughout the other pages of the program ...

I also use the **Post-Redirect-Get Pattern** in the action() method  with a redirection to the same page (to avoid to submit twice the data ) . 
The problem lies there ! I redirect via a `header('location')`.
I thought the `header()` ended the script immediatly but in fact (because of the buffering !!) it continues to the end and then php send the headers ...

I put a `die()` after the `header('location')` and after that everything went fine.

I've learned something new / That's nice !